# Having trouble with a switch statement in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

Hello I need help with a switch statement in c#. i'm showing an element depending of the userRole.
I am getting the userRole fine because i use the code in another page(the role)
bit i'm having trouble passing the role to the switch statement.

```
    protected void Page_Load()
    {
        string userRole = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            // Get current logged in usename
            string username = User.Identity.Name;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
            {
                userRole = "isanonymus";
            }
            else
            {
                Compras entity = new Compras();
                AspNetUser user = entity.AspNetUsers.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(username)).FirstOrDefault();
                // get role of current logged in user
                userRole = user.AspNetRoles.First().Name.ToLower();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            userRole = string.Empty;
        }
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ToWhom(userRole);
        }

    }
    private void ToWhom(string userRole)
    {
        switch (userRole)
        {
            case "employee":
                return EmployeeView.Visible = true;
            case "supplier":
                return SupplierView.Visible = true;
            default:
                return GenericView.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

this is the error i get:
Error   CS0127  Since 'Manage.ToWhom(string)' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

Comment: Use break not return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you are trying to return a value, which will be a bool. You need to just break from the switch case statement using the method below.
You need to change this.

```
private void ToWhom(string userRole)
{
    switch (userRole)
    {
        case "employee":
            return EmployeeView.Visible = true;
        case "supplier":
            return SupplierView.Visible = true;
        default:
            return GenericView.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

To this.

```
private void ToWhom(string userRole)
{
    switch (userRole)
    {
        case "employee":
            EmployeeView.Visible = true;
            break;
        case "supplier":
           SupplierView.Visible = true;
            break;
        default:
            GenericView.Visible = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your default case is invalid.

Comment: @StillLearnin Thanks i copied the break point into the wrong spot.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cant return from a void method.

Comment: @UnicornoMarley I never said you could. You should read what I wrote.

Answer (score 2):

There are two changes in the code. First is the return type will not be void as you are returning bool type to return. Secondly you need to put break for each case

```
private bool ToWhom(string userRole)
{
    switch (userRole)
    {
        case "employee":
            return EmployeeView.Visible = true;
            break;
        case "supplier":
            return SupplierView.Visible = true;
            break;
        default:
            return GenericView.Visible = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

if in case you want the function to be `void` just remove the `return` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Change your function to be:

```
 private void ToWhom(string userRole)
    {
        switch (userRole)
        {
            case "employee":
                 EmployeeView.Visible = true;
                 break;
            case "supplier":
                SupplierView.Visible = true;
                break;
            default:
                GenericView.Visible = true;
                break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set the function to not return a value by using the void keyword thus the compiler gives an Error because you do return values.

You can either change the function from void to the appropriate type and return the value or pass a parameter by reference and set it to the value in the switch statement.